# Como divulgar o nosso site?

Tags: discussion

<s>Sei que não é o momento de falar disto, devido ainda estarmos em *beta privado*</s>

Penso eu que talvez poderíamos começar a pensar em públicos para divulgar, como por exemplo, estudantes de qualquer área que trabalhe com "textos", estudantes de jornalismo, escritores e outros tipos de pessoas que possam vir a se interessar pelo assunto do site.

Gostaria de debater quais são os públicos que podem se interessar e meios de divulgação poderíamos usar (sugiram ideias).

Eu pessoalmente gostei muito do site e tenho uma boa perspectiva dele, acho que a divulgação pode ajudar em muito feita pelos colaboradores pode ajudar muito.

Que tipo de divulgação segure que colaboradores podemos fazer?

---

<s>I understand it is not the time to talk about this, because we are still in *private beta*</s>

However I think maybe we could start thinking about the audience that we want to bring forth

For example, students from any area that works with "texts", *students of journalism*, *writers* and other people that may be interested.

I would like to discuss which public and means of dissemination (suggest ideas).

I think the site has potential and the disclosure *made by users* can be of great help.

What kind of disclosure that hold users (we the users) can do?

Answer (score 5):

I believe we already have a tool, but not so much "public".

I'm already checking my contacts list, looking for potential experts and enthusiasts so I can send invites. On all site pages, right column:

[image]

Acho que já temos uma ferramenta, mas não tão pública.

Estou conferindo minha lista de contatos procurando por potenciais *experts* e entusiastas para mandar convites. O boxe fica na coluna da direita em todas as páginas do site (aparentemente).

---

As social engagement, I'd recommend scanning the site Social Bakers. Below a link showing YouTube top audience sites for Education in YouTube Brazil (site also has data on Facebook, Twitter and G+). Just go there, find cool people and spread the word :)

Como ferramenta social, eu recomendaria fuçar o site Social Bakers.
Abaixo um link mostrando as melhores audiencias sobre Educação no YouTube Brasil (o site também tem dados sobre Facebook, Twitter e G+). É só ir lá, achar gente legal e espalhar a notícia :)

http://www.socialbakers.com/statistics/youtube/channels/brazil/society/education/

Comment: Sim a ferramenta que indicou parece ser o gatilho :) +1. No entanto acho que não me expressei direito, a ideia é divulgar após o beta privado. Como chegar até aos usuários que podem se interessar pelo site? Note que não conheço jornalistas e nem escritores. Se tiver alguma sugestão eu ficaria agradecido!

Comment: Guilherme, talvez seja eu quem não li direito. Updated answer.

Comment: Muito bom mesmo vou ver, esta resposta seria uma boa pra postar em: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/633/3635 :) - se pude-se seria +10

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid I do not understand the implications of us being *beta privado*, so I'm not sure we can do what I've just seen done in the SE German Language. I [posted a question there](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25528/was-ist-die-genaue-bedeutung-von-zynisch), and a little while later someone [had twitted it](https://twitter.com/StackGerman/status/643124760839385088). Are we twitting yet? Can we do it?

UPDATE. I was mightily ignorant. Well, I still am, but not on this particular topic anymore. All you have to do is click on **share** at the bottom left of any post, and select the medium. I've just posted one question on facebook. It's on my timeline now. I suppose we all could do this.

Comment: Yes, I believe we can tweet, so I created a Twitter account for this, really use social networks can help :)

Comment: @Guilherme So we should look into it. I don't use twitter myself, so I don't know how it works. I don't know how it works from the point of view of StackExchange either: whether anyone can tweet any question, or whether you need a previlege to do that? Don't know how to go from here

Comment: No needs, use share link in footer post, it's public :) Even users not registered can do so.

Comment: @Guilherme Já vi. Vou divulgar a minha pegunta do jajão no fb para ver o que acontece

Comment: @Guilherme Já agora, não ficaste muito entusiasmado com a minha ideia de reformular o título da tua pergunta sobre os Cínicos? Ou talvez o meu comentário te tenha passado despercebido...

Comment: Jacinto nao passou nao, mas o titulo que sugeriu soa diferente pra duvida, a minha ideia e que isto seja uma questao regional e ate o momento que eu criei a pergunta eu nao sabia se realmente ambas tinham mesma origem, acreditava ser algum tipo de "neologismo", mas olhando o meu titulo original, sim o seu titulo esta um pouco melhor (na verdade o meu titulo esta muito ruim pra entender). Ainda nao escolhi a sua resposta, mas prometo que vou ler e estudar um pouco nos proximos dias pra entender melhor a situacao. Obrigado por enquanto.

Comment: @Guilherme Tudo bem, vê lá isso com tempo. Achei aquilo muito interessante mesmo. Há pelo menos cinco línguas (na verdade acho que todas as línguas europeias tem uma palavra com a mesma origem de cínico) que eu vi, e nos significados há algumas semelhanças entre o espanhol e o português, e entre o francês e um dos significados em alemão. De resto é tudo diferente!